# Reducing AWS Data Transfer Cost for AWS S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS S3 has a standard public bucket and folder (*Asia Pacific region*) which hosts ~30 GB of images/media. On another hand, the website and app access these images by using a direct S3 object URL. Unknowingly we run into high data transfer cost and its significantly unproportionate:

1. Amazon Simple Storage Service: USD 30
2. AWS Data Transfer: USD 110

I have also read that if EC2 and S3 is in the same region cost will be significantly lower, but problem is S3 objects are accessible from anywhere in the world from client machine directly and no EC2 is involved in between.

Can someone please suggest how can data transfer costs be reduced?

Comment: Could you please clarify -- are the objects in Amazon S3 being accessed by end users in the browser, or are they being used by the Amazon EC2 instances (without going out to end users)?

Comment: Please clarify what the USD 30 charge is relating to. Is it just storage & request charges? Are you only concerned about the Data Transfer charge? What do you mean by "significantly unproportionate"?

Comment: Hello John, objects in s3 buckets are public and accessed by website, this website is accessed by end user without authentication. USD 30 was just S3 storage cost and I am concerned about data transfer charges.

Answer (score 2):

The **Data Transfer** charge is directly related to the amount of information that goes **from AWS to the Internet**. Depending on your region, it is typically charged at 9c/GB.

If you are concerned about the Data Transfer charge, there are a few things you could do:

- Activate [Amazon S3 Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html), which will create a log file for each web request. You can then see **how many requests are coming** and possibly **detect strange access behaviour** (eg bots, search engines, abuse).
- You could try **reducing the size of files** that are typically accessed, such as making images smaller. Take a look at the Access Logs and determine which objects are being accessed the most, and are therefore causing the most costs.
- Use less large files on your website (eg videos). Again, look at the Access Logs to determine where the data is being used.

A cost of $110 suggests about 1.2TB of data being transferred.

Comment: Hello John, may I ask if I can: 1. Put rate limit where configuration like 500 requests per minute is allowed; 2. Put cloundfront to reduce data flow, will it help because data is cached?; 3. Any other idea you might think aloud? Again thank you for the help.

Comment: (1) There is no ability to configure such "requests per minute" limits and you should _not_ be wanting to use such limits because it would affect your users' ability to use your service.  (2) CloudFront has similar Data Transfer costs (in some countries, it can cost even more). (3) You could consider using **AWS Lightsail** because its [pricing plans](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/) include an amount of Data Transfer. However, this would need a change of architecture.